# What is GL_VERSION and should I consider it when I want to choose one of openGLES versions?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am about to choose a version of OpenGLES for my next project,Since I like shaders program very much, I find them usefull, I do not like to use OpenGLES 1.0 it also getting deprecated.

Having these on mind,I went to choose from 2.0 or 3.0 or even 3.1, I checked [Khronos conformant product](https://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products#opengles) to see which devices support 3.0 and which ones still support 2.0,

But I found it very confusing because :

1.There is Apple Inc, Iphone 6 and 6 plus for all version of OpenGLES

> OpenGLES 3.0 2015-08-29
>
> OpenGLES 2.0 2014-10-19
>
> *OpenGLES 1.0 2014-10-19*

Does this means that there are some iphone 6 in market that only support OpenGLES 1.0? if yes, that would be very strange and I wonder how can I ask for one which supports 3.0 and would the apple store guys know about it? for example will they say don’t pick that one, cause its a 1.0!

2.The other confusing thing was the GL_VERSION in that table(conformant product) if you check all the rows relevant to iPhone6 for example, you will see the following records :

> Apple Inc. Iphone 6,6+ GL_VERSION "OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 Apple A8 GPU - 50.5.1”
>
> Apple Inc. Iphone 6,6+ GL_VERSION "OpenGL ES 2.0 Apple A8 GPU - 50.5.1"
>
> Apple Inc. Iphone 6,6+ GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES 3.0 Apple A8 GPU - 50.5.
>
> Apple Inc. Iphone 6,6+ GL_VERSION: OpenGL ES 3.0 Apple A8 GPU - 53.13

by looking at the GL_VERSION you see OpenGL 1.1 and 2.0 have same GL_Version so it doesn’t show the version of openGLES.
What is it? I know that I may get its value via `glGetString​(GL_VERSION)` but why whould I?

Comment: According to the information on the Apple developer site (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1) ES 2.0 is supported on the iPhone 3GS and later, 3.0 on the iPhone 5s and later.

Comment: Reto,Thanks, I checked it too, Its a little bit disappointing that 4 and 4s does not support OpenGL 2.0, and still a lot of people has 4,4s or even the older models.

Comment: 3GS is the earliest that supports 2.0, so this certainly includes 4 and 4s.

Comment: Yeah,that was a misunderstanding, Ok then I think I go for openGLES 2.0 and disregarding that benefits of VBO and VAO in 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All iPhone6 support OpenGLES 1, 2 and 3. This is a good reference for seeing which versions of GLES are supported by different iOS devices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices (there's a row called 'OpenGL ES' which shows the highest GLES version supported, but all the devices support the older versions too - i.e. a device listed as supporting GLES 3 also supports GLES 2 and 1).
2. GL_VERSION is partially a vendor specific version string. It takes the form "OpenGL ES N.M vendor-specific information". What the vendor specific information is telling you is the version of the OpenGLES driver. This is rarely useful information. A developer would typically only use this to work around known bugs on specific driver revisions.

Comment: Well, so why opegles 1.0 and 2.0 both have the same GLVersion? is it a coincidance?

Comment: I would presume there's a single large codebase for all of their GLES implementations and the 1.0 and 2.0 drivers happened to be built at the same time.